# What are the "sirisha-bowers" in Sarojini Naidu's 'Indian Love Song'?

Tags: meaning, poetry, sarojini-naidu

This is the first stanza of Sarojini Naidu's wonderfully evocative poem *[Indian Love Song](https://mypoeticside.com/show-classic-poem-20408)*:

> She
> Like a serpent to the calling voice of flutes,
> Glides my heart into thy fingers, O my Love!
> Where the night-wind, like a lover, leans above
> His jasmine-gardens and **sirisha-bowers**;
> And on ripe boughs of many-coloured fruits
> Bright parrots cluster like vermilion flowers.

What exactly are these *sirisha-bowers*? They seem to be some kind of botanical entity, and *sirisha* is probably the name of some type of plant, but which? (I speak Hindi and don't recognize this word, and Google doesn't seem to either.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [शिरीष (śirīṣa)](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B7), known in English under various names: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albizia_lebbeck) gives “siris, Indian siris, East Indian walnut, Broome raintree, lebbeck, lebbek tree, frywood, koko and woman’s tongue”. Here’s an entry in a Sanskrit–English dictionary, roughly contemporary with Naidu, showing the “sirisha” spelling used in the poem:

> The *Sirisha* tree.—शिरीष *n.*
>
> <sub>M. S. Gole (1915). [*Amarasara, or an Abridgment of Amarakosha, being a Sanskrit–English Pocket Dictionary*, p. 82](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.528739/page/n93/mode/2up). Poona: Chitrashala Press.</sub>

The botanical name is [*Albizia lebbeck*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albizia_lebbeck), but synonyms include *Mimosa sirissa*, due to [William Roxburgh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Roxburgh):

> M[imosa] *Sirissa*. R.
>
> Arboreous. *Leaves* bipinnate, *pinnae* from two to three pair. *Spikes* axillary, round; corollets monadelphous. *Segments* leafy, dry, long-linear and broad, not opening spontaneously.
>
> Sirisha, or Shirish in Sanscrit and Bengalee. […]
>
> This tree is very common in every part of India; all soils and situations seem to please it equally. It grows to be a pretty large tree, but with a short thick trunk covered with ash-coloured bark. It has a very extensive but thin head. Flowering time the hot and rainy season; the greatest part of its leaves drop during the cold season. […]
>
> The wood of this tree, is much like that of *M. Xylocarpa*, and equally serviceable. The flowers are very fragrant. I have often seen large masses of very pure gum upon it.
>
> <sub>William Roxburgh (1832). [*Flora Indica; or, Descriptions of Indian Plants*, volume 2, pp. 544–545](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.220900/page/n553/mode/2up). Serampore: W. Thacker.</sub>

[image]
<sub>*Albizia lebbeck*, Jayaprakash Nagar, Bangalore. Photo by Forestowlet. Public domain.</sub>